# Angular json-editor (change) event not getting called post ngIf toggle

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular-ng-if, jsoneditor

Using json-edit from npm ang-jsoneditor inside a modal pop up.
Popup is toggled using ngIf

I want to save changes in json-edior.

Code works fine when first time ngIf condition is true and modal pop up appear. Change event get fired.

If ngIf remove and display pop up second time; change event is not getting fired and I don't get updated json in json-editor

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition">
<div> //modal
<div>  //modal pop up header</div>
<div>  //modal pop up body 
<json-editor  id="jEditor"  [options]="config"  [data]="data" (change)="onChangeData($event)" </json-editor>
                
                  <button  (click)="closeDialog('fixed')"> Cancel</button>
                  <button (click)="saveJson()" >Save</button>
                
</div>
</ng-container>
```

Tried below scenario still change event not getting fired

1. Two way binding using ngModel
2. Pass data in click of button

In developer tool of browser, I can see change event listener. Still change event not getting called

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could try. It looks like json-editor might have its own version of change detection ([check here](https://github.com/mariohmol/ang-jsoneditor/blob/master/src/app/demo/demo.component.html#L28)).

Also, please make sure you are updating `data` properly in `saveJson()`.

Finally, you could try using `(ngModelChange)` in conjunction with `ngModel` ([ref](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/frontend-interview-question-what-is-the-difference-between-change-vs-ngmodelchange-f6bb3cb26dbc)).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Tried with all the solutions mentioned in link. No updated data once ngIf condition toggle the div containing json-editor

Comment: Instead now controlling visibility of the div using styles and able to get updated json in json-editor on button click event.